# Use bzr/git/hg to move SVN repo to a sub-dir in another repo

Tags: svn, clone, dvcs

I have 2 repos that I would like to merge into one as the projects should be together.
They look something like this:

```
Repo1
   --branches
   --tags
   --trunk
       --Projects
           --Project1
```

--

```
Repo2
   --branches
   --tags
   --trunk
       --Project2
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
Repo1
   --branches
   --tags
   --trunk
       --Projects
           --Project1
           --Project2
```

Basically move Project2 into Repo1 whilst keeping its history (not interested in branches though).

I think that this could be done with svnadmin and svndumpfilter but my svn admin says he doesn't want the hassle and that I should just commit the latest revision :(

Can I get around this by using bzr or git or hg to clone Repo2 then push it to Repo1 in the correct directory?

I'm not familiar with any of the DVCSs, so commands to do it with any of them are welcome.

Comment: Do you want to put the results back into svn, or simply have the full history for both?

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to add bzr/git/hg into the mix will only make things more complicated.  Any approach requires that you pull every revision from the repository, which existing tools expect you have direct access to the repo files.  If your svn admin won't do it for you, can you at least get access to the repo files so you can run svndumpfilter yourself?

If you can't get access to the repo files, you're probably on your own since your real problem is an uncooperative admin, not a lack of tools.  In that case, the option I can think of is to write a script that checks out each revision and commits it to the new repository, but that will probably turn into a bigger project than you planned on.